# Get list inside list in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, arraylist

I have this table in google spread sheet.
[spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSHvg.jpg)

**table head is merged**

|  | Monday |  |  | Tuesday |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Morning | Afternoon | Evening | Morning | Afternoon | Evening |
| Breakfast | Pick Bro | Dinner | Breakfast | Pick Bro | Dinner |
| Cleaning House |  | Reading Book | Reading Book |  | Go to Grand Dad |

with get range

```
function testing() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var gr = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:F4").getValues();
  Logger.log(gr)
}
```

I got

```
[
 [Monday, , , Tuesday, , ],
 [Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Morning, Afternoon, Evening],
 [Breakfast, Pick Bro, Dinner, Breakfast, Pick Sis, Dinner],
 [Cleaning House, , Reading Book, Reading Book, , Go to Grand Dad]
]
```

But the result I need to do loop is

```
[
 [Monday,
  [Morning,[Breakfast,Cleaning House]]
  [Afternoon,[Pick Bro]]
  [Evening,[Dinner,Reading Book]]
 ],
 [Tuesday,
  [Morning,[Breakfast,Reading Book]]
  [Afternoon,[Pick Sis]]
  [Evening,[Dinner,Go to Grand Dad]]
 ],
]
```

it looks like looping by column, not row. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion using Google Apps Script.

  - From

    |  | Monday |  |  | Tuesday |  |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | Morning | Afternoon | Evening | Morning | Afternoon | Evening |
    | Breakfast | Pick Bro | Dinner | Breakfast | Pick Bro | Dinner |
    | Cleaning House |  | Reading Book | Reading Book |  | Go to Grand Dad |
  - To

    ```
      [
       [Monday,
        [Morning,[Breakfast,Cleaning House]]
        [Afternoon,[Pick Bro]]
        [Evening,[Dinner,Reading Book]]
       ],
       [Tuesday,
        [Morning,[Breakfast,Reading Book]]
        [Afternoon,[Pick Sis]]
        [Evening,[Dinner,Go to Grand Dad]]
       ],
      ]
    ```

In this case, I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve the merged ranges from the header row.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var mergedRanges = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getMergedRanges();

  // 2. Retrieve the header and values.
  var [header, ...values] = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:F4").getValues();

  // 3. Transpose the values.
  var ar = values[0].map((_, i) => {
    const [h, ...v] = values.map(row => row[i]);
    return [h, v.filter(String)];
  });
  
  // 4. Create an result array using the meadedRanges and the transposed values.
  var res = header.filter(String).map((r, i) => [r, ...ar.splice(0, mergedRanges[i].getNumColumns())]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
}
```

- The flow of this script is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the merged ranges from the header row.
  2. Retrieve the header and values.
  3. Transpose the values.
  4. Create an result array using the meadedRanges and the transposed values.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
[
  ["Monday",
    ["Morning",["Breakfast","Cleaning House"]],
    ["Afternoon",["Pick Bro"]],
    ["Evening",["Dinner","Reading Book"]]
  ],
  ["Tuesday",
    ["Morning",["Breakfast","Reading Book"]],
    ["Afternoon",["Pick Bro"]],
    ["Evening",["Dinner","Go to Grand Dad"]]
  ]
]
```

#### References:

- [getMergedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)